# Recursive functions on Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm currently learning Mathematica and was reading through some lecture notes which were trying to explain recursive functions, they then went on to give the following examples:

```
mapg[list_] := Prepend[  mapg[Rest[list]] , g[First[list]] ]; 

mapg[{}] := {};

mapg[{a, b, c}]
```

which gives the output: {g[a], g[b], g[c]}

While I understand the meaning of the individual functions (Prepend, Rest, First), I don't understand how this is a recursive function and how it actually works to give the output that it gives.

Another example given is:

```
primefactorial[1] := 1;

primefactorial[n_] := If[PrimeQ[n], n # , #] &@primefactorial[n - 1]

primefactorial /@ Range[23]
```

Which gives the output: {1, 2, 6, 6, 30, 30, 210, 210, 210, 210, 2310, 2310, 30030, 30030,
30030, 30030, 510510, 510510, 9699690, 9699690, 9699690, 9699690,
223092870}

Again, while I understand what the PrimeQ function does and the If function, I'm confused about what the actual recursive function is doing. In particular what does "n #" do in the If function? Also what does @primefactorial[n-1] do? What is being applied to primefactorial[n-1] exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one

```js
mapg[list_] := Prepend[  mapg[Rest[list]] , g[First[list]] ]; 

mapg[{}] := {};

mapg[{a, b, c}]
```

is just a way to write `Map[g, list]` by prepending `g[First[list]]` to `mapg[Rest[list]]`. The key part here is that they've defined

```js
mapg[{}] = {}
```

so that there's a concrete base case & you don't recurse infinitely. This works because

```js
Rest[{a}] == {}
```

If you unwrap what's happening step-wise in that call you get

```js
mapg[{a, b, c}] == Prepend[Prepend[Prepend[{}, c], b], a]
```

The second case is a bit more subtle, since they've used pure (anonymous) function notation. In this case they have

```js
If[PrimeQ[n], n # , #] &@primefactorial[n - 1] == 
  If[PrimeQ[n], n*primefactorial[n - 1], primefactorial[n - 1]]
```

which just says if `n` is a prime number, then multiply it by the previous factorial expansion, otherwise do nothing and just return the previous expansion.

The recursion comes in the `primefactorial[n - 1]` step, where again to prevent infinite recursion they've defined

```js
primefactorial[1] = 1
```

You could symbolically expand this like

```js
symbolicPrimeFactorial[1] := prime[1];
symbolicPrimeFactorial[n_] := If[PrimeQ[n], prime[n]*#, #] &@symbolicPrimeFactorial[n - 1]

symbolicPrimeFactorial /@ Range[1, 23, 2] // Column

prime[1]
prime[1] prime[2] prime[3]
prime[1] prime[2] prime[3] prime[5]
prime[1] prime[2] prime[3] prime[5] prime[7]
prime[1] prime[2] prime[3] prime[5] prime[7]
prime[1] prime[2] prime[3] prime[5] prime[7] prime[11]
prime[1] prime[2] prime[3] prime[5] prime[7] prime[11] prime[13]
prime[1] prime[2] prime[3] prime[5] prime[7] prime[11] prime[13]
prime[1] prime[2] prime[3] prime[5] prime[7] prime[11] prime[13] prime[17]
prime[1] prime[2] prime[3] prime[5] prime[7] prime[11] prime[13] prime[17] prime[19]
prime[1] prime[2] prime[3] prime[5] prime[7] prime[11] prime[13] prime[17] prime[19]
prime[1] prime[2] prime[3] prime[5] prime[7] prime[11] prime[13] prime[17] prime[19] prime[23]
```

and hopefully this is pretty clear as to what's going on

Comment: Thank you so much! 

I just had a quick question about the first example, when you mentioned unwrapping to see what's happening stepwise and wrote:
```mapg[{a, b, c}] == Prepend[Prepend[Prepend[{}, c], b], a]```
Why is it not, 
```mapg[{a, b, c}] == Prepend[Prepend[Prepend[{}, g[c]], g[b]], g[a]]```
instead? Or have I misunderstood your explanation?

Comment: @user839136 it is that, I just forgot the `g` wrapping. Of course, it should be noted that we’d never actually just a function like that. Much better to use `Map` instead